# How to pin a container or any other widget below appbar in scroll view in flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I want a widget to be place below the app while scrolling the screen . 
The screen contains a floating app bar with flexible space ( sliverappbar) and below it one conatiner which have any container or tab view .
The video in the link is the example of the effect i wanted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, I think I understand you now. You'll need to implement a CustomScrollView

```
CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                    // Your appbar goes here
                    ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: PersistentHeader(
                    widget: Row(
                      // Format this to meet your need
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Hello World'),
                        Text('Hello World'),
                        Text('Hello World'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Create a new class for the Persistent header, which extends a SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate as shown:

```
class PersistentHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget widget;

  PersistentHeader({this.widget});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 56.0,
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: Center(child: widget),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 56.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 56.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Let me know if you encounter any other issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Any idea how to stop it from going behind the status bar?

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out yet? @Chris

Comment: no I gave up on this one in the end. Couldn't get it to do what I wanted

Comment: Great solution!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea of a solution to your particular problem, having recently implemented something quite similar or identical to what you want, but I can't find the link you talked about to the video of the effect you're trying to achieve. Could you edit and upload the link to the video so I can view to enable me to render the precise solution to your problem?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PhEBRzoZgYhKrJ5xK2xe2ebOWqw2_8vW/view?usp=drivesdk    <----  as this is not the exact the want i wanted but you can see in this video below appbar there is widget which is pin above the list view .