# How could I implement that effect in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How Could I Implement [this kind of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Yc1.jpg)?
I tried two `SilverAppBar` but it leads to a big blank strip between the two bars!

It's the same effect on the Facebook Mobile application on the home page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverAppBar(
                  title: Text('The App'),

                ),
                SliverAppBar(
                  title: Row(
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(
                        6, (index) => Icon(Icons.access_alarm,color: Colors.grey,)),
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  ),
                  pinned: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(List<Widget>.generate(
                        100, (index) => Text(index.toString()))))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put your code! what you have tried ?

Comment: Please post all the required reading for your question **here**, nobody will follow external links.

Comment: The Link is for a video demonstrating the effect I try to implement

Comment: i found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127826/how-to-pin-a-container-or-any-other-widget-below-appbar-in-scroll-view-in-flutte